# How can I set the default target for InAppBrowser

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

Currently I am using [ngx-twitter-timeline](https://github.com/ABD-dev/ngx-twitter-timeline) to display an embedded Twitter timeline within my [Ionic 4](https://ionicframework.com/docs/) app, but if a user clicks or taps on a Tweet then the app will open a link to twitter and the web view takes over control of the app. I am hoping to use the [InAppBrowser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) plugin to make any external links opened within the app to open using the InAppBrowser popup. This would allow me to display the back button and location bar.

How can I achieve this? I know that InAppBrowser can replace the `window.open` method, but I need to somehow set the `target` to `_blank` inorder to have the URLS open in the InAppBrowser control so users can click 'back' within the location bar.

You can see what currently happens in the Gif below...

https://i.imgur.com/L0luPBf.gifv